# Gridster auto resize by content height

Tags: javascript, gridster

I am trying to append content inside a Gridster widget but with no luck for two days already. I tried with:

```
.resize_widget( $widget, [size_x], [size_y], [reposition], [callback] )
```

but the sizes x and y only accept numbers - its default re-sizing mechanism and they are not pixels. They are some sort of steps. If I increment with +1 the size_y the widget is re-sized more than needed and again with its own mechanism.
I was also looking for a way to reduce this step. No luck.
I also tried to change the widget height, min-height, etc. It was not re-sizing.
Do you have any suggestions, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone comes to this question later.

The x and y numbers are the number of columns and rows a widget takes up. You define the number of rows and columns, as well as the width and height of each when you create the gridster grid.